# Eclipse class hierarchy

Tags: oop, inheritance, class-design

In pure Object Orientation thinking do make sense to have a classes hierarchy like this:

**IPerson**  (Interface) base class for

- name
- surname
- etc ...

**Employee** (may be an Abstract Class or not)

- employee_id
- level
- department

**FreeLance** (- hourly_rate) and  **PermanentEmployee** (- salary)

My personal feeling (that's my question) is that in Eclipse the developer is encouraged to have a class hierarchy made by Interface - Class ... (without abstract class in the middle). Am I correct/wrong? 
the warning:

*Method 'XXX' is not designed for extension - needs to be abstract, final or empty.*

doesn't prove that? 
thanks a lot for you feedback!

_ _

Kasper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces describe *'roles'* of an instance while abstract classes describe *common functionality*. If you have common functionality that puts all its derivatives in a specific role than an abstract class that implements (partially) an interface is perfectly fine.

If you just need an abstraction, then you can also go for the abstract class I would say.